# How do I compile in Xcode using gcc with -ansi -pedantic?

Tags: c, gcc, xcode5

I need to compile a code written in C using gcc (in Xcode) with flag options -ansi -pedantic. I know how to change the compiler to gcc, however I don't know how to change the flags.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Other C Flags build setting to add compiler flags that aren't available in Xcode's build settings editor.